# The epigraph of a semi-convex function has positive reach

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, convex-geometry, convex-analysis

I've been trying to prove the following theorem for several hours with no result so far.

**Claim.** Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a *semi-convex* function, i.e. there exists a constant $C > 0$ such that $f(x) + C x^2$ is convex. Let $\operatorname{epi}(f) := \{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2;\ f(x)\leq y \}$ denote the epigraph of $f$. Then the *reach* of $A = \operatorname{epi}(f)$ is positive, i.e. there exists $r > 0$ such that, for any point $(x,y)$ at distance less than $r$ to $A$, there exists a unique point in $A$ nearest to $(x,y)$.

I'll be really grateful for any help!

Thank you.

Comment: What is the reach of a set?

Comment: The original Federer's definition: [link](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1959-093-03/S0002-9947-1959-0110078-1/) page 15 (p 432)

Comment: Perhaps you could provide the definition of reach in the question.

Comment: If you can reduce the problem to the case (by an adequate change of coordinates?) where $f(0)=0$, $f$ is even and there is a sequence $(0,-\epsilon_n)$ with two closest points (therefore strictly below the horizontal axis on the graph), you are done, I think, as for any finite constant, $C$, $f(x)+Cx^2$ would not be convex in zero.

Answer (score 3):

There is a complete discussion of this question, in general dimensions (it is true there too), in my thesis, published in Duke Math J. 1985.

Answer (score 1):

Taking $r < \frac{1}{2C}$ should work. Indeed, if a circle of radius $r$ touches the graph of $f$ by below at two points, then the curvature $$\kappa(x) = \frac{f''(x)}{(1+(f'(x))^2)^{3/2}}$$ is larger than $-\frac{1}{r}$ at the touching points. Since $f$ lies above the circle, $\kappa \leq -\frac{1}{r}$ somewhere in between the touching points, hence $f'' \leq -\frac{1}{r}$ there. Semiconvexity completes the proof.